# WiFi problems on HP Probook 4520S running 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, connection, realtek

I have an HP ProBook 4520s that I have just installed 16.04 on. 
It's impossible to get wifi to connect. Connects fine via LAN.

`iwconfig` returns :

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

ens5      no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
```

Comment: Please post the output of : inxi -N -z

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @albertj Why do you ask this command? The output will be: `command not found`.

Comment: Also add results for `rfkill list all` to your question